# converting a string with commas to a array with commas (or even just a number with commas

Tags: javascript, max-msp-jitter

I'm using JS inside MaxMSP

I would like to take a string output (of separated by comma single fibonacci numbers) and convert it to either an array or number, keeping the space and commas but getting ride of the "double quotes"

I've tried a bunch of stuff here but unfortunately I'm still banging my head against the wall.

```
autowatch = 1;

inlets = 2;
outlets = 2;


function msg_int(num){

  var a = 1; 
  var b = 0, temp;


  while (num >= 0){
    temp = a;
    a = a + b;
    b = temp;
    num--;
    outlet(0, b);


    var n = temp;
    digits = n.toString().replace(/(\d{1})/g,'$1, ')
    outlet(1, digits);


  }
    return b;


}
```

The Input number is 14
The first outlet(0) number is 610
The second outlet(1) is "6, 1, 0, "

I would like the second outlet to be 6, 1, 0,

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = '"6, 1, 0,"'.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
console.info(result);
```

Comment: Why not? This would work for all strings. Do you have an example of unknown strings? I'll add those to my answer.

Comment: this actually outputs "6, 1, 0," for me
`
//
// fibonacci sequence
//

autowatch = 1;

inlets = 2;
outlets = 2;


function msg_int(num){
  
  var a = 1; 
  var b = 0, temp;




  while (num >= 0){
    temp = a;
    a = a + b;
    b = temp;
    num--;
    outlet(0, b);


  
    var result = '"6, 1, 0,"'.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
    outlet(1, result);


  }
    return b;
}
`

Comment: What is `outlet()` ? If your code `outlet` is a number and not a function.

Comment: you can think of outlet like console.log in MaxMSP

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want `outlet(1)` to output a Max “list” as opposed to a symbol. `outlet` will handle that for you, but you need to hand it an array to achieve this. Here’s what it says [in the docs](https://docs.cycling74.com/max7/vignettes/jsglobal#outlet):

> If the argument to outlet is an array, it is unrolled (to one level only) and passed as a Max message or list (depending on whether the first element of the array is a number or string).

Knowing this, you need to convert `digits` into an array before passing it to `outlet`:

```js
var n = temp;
var digits = n.toString(); // convert 610 to "610" (for example)
digits.split("");          // split "610" into ["6", "1", "0"]
outlet(1, digits);
```

Whether this a Max list or message depends on the type of the first element, so if you need a list of numbers (integers in your case), you could do something like this before passing it to outlet:

```js
// map ["6", "1", "0"] to [6, 1, 0]
digits = digits.map(function (i) { return parseInt(i) });
```